# Явные специализации шаблона в cpp файле

Tags: c++, классы, visual-c++, шаблоны-с++

Как написать явные специализации для разных типов в другом cpp файле. На мой взгляд все писать в хедере не очень удобно и понятно. Есть шаблонный класс Array

```
//head.h:
template<typename Type>
class Array
{
    Type* p;
    size_t size;
    mutable int error;
    static int count;
public:
 //...
    template<typename T>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Array<T>&);
};

template<typename Type>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Array<Type>& a)
{
    if (a.size)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size; i++)
            os << a.p[i] << "  ";
    }
    return os;
}
```

И есть специализация для типа char (я понимаю что тут можно просто сделать приведение к типу int и не париться, но мне важен сам метод определения шаблонов):

```
template<>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Array<char>& a)
{
    if (a.size)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size; i++)
            os << int(a.p[i]) << "  ";
    }
    return os;
}
```

Она работает если написана в хедере, либо в main.cpp. Если я пытаюсь определить в другом cpp файле то получаю ошибки:

```
Ошибка  LNK2005 "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator<<<char>(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class Array<char> const &)" (??$?6D@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@ABV?$Array@D@@@Z) уже определен в main.obj   

Ошибка  LNK1169 обнаружен многократно определенный символ - один или более  (файл arr_11.exe)
```

Ведь как я понял явная специализация это уже готовый вариант функции, и компилятор там не будет ничего генерировать для char. Значит можно и определить в другом cpp файле.

Comment: Представьте, что у вас получился объектный файл со специализацией вместо файла исходника. Выходит, шаблон потеряет эту специализацию?

Comment: Что значит "все писать в хедере"? Явные специализации функций (если они не inline) обязаны сидеть именно в cpp файле. Других вариантов нет.

Comment: Так я согласен, но не получается определить в cpp файле, хотя в main.cpp откуда вызываю функцию все работает.

Comment: "Она работает если написана в хедере" - вы что-то выдумываете. Если такую явную специализацию написать в хедере, то при его включении в несколько `.cpp` файлов будет именно LNK2005. Явную специализацию неинлайновой функции ни в коем случае нельзя помещать в хедер.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Явная специализация шаблона функции является *обычной функцией* и объявляться/определяться должна по общим правилам для обычных функций.

1. Если специализация определяет inline-функцию, то ее определение должно находиться в заголовочном файле

   ```
   template<>
   inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Array<char>& a)
   {
     ...
   }
   ```
2. Если специализация определяет не-inline функцию, то в заголовочном файле должно находиться только ее объявление

   ```
   template<>
   std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Array<char>& a);
   ```

   а определение должно располагаться в одном из файлов реализации

   ```
   template<>
   std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Array<char>& a)
   {
     ...
   }
   ```